# Detect when an Asset has been applied (dropped in the viewport)

Tags: python, asset-browser

So far this has been the way I check if World asset has been dropped in the viewport:

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def depsgraph_handler(scene, depsgraph):
    for update in depsgraph.updates:
        if update.id.bl_rna.name == 'World':
            print('redraw world here')

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(depsgraph_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.remove(depsgraph_handler)
```

Is there a more robust way of doing it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282286/bpy-do-something-every-time-an-object-is-added