# bpy do something every time an object is added

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

How can I make a condition for every time a new object is added to the scene? Example: Every time an object is added, it's given a triangulate modifier?

Comment: You can monitor the dependency graph with a handler, and every time it is updated compare an old list of objects to the current list of objects and if a new one is found add your modifier to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @[Psyonic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/60765/psyonic) has mentioned: *You can monitor the dependency graph with a handler, and every time it is updated compare an old list of objects to the current list of objects. And if a new one is found add your modifier to it.*

Here's the working script:

```
import bpy

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.clear()

previous_objects = set(bpy.data.objects)

def add_triangulate_modifier(obj):
    for mod in obj.modifiers:
        if mod.type == "TRIANGULATE":
            return
    mod = obj.modifiers.new(name="Triangulate", type='TRIANGULATE')

def new_object_added(scene):
    global previous_objects

    current_objects = set(bpy.data.objects)
    new_objects = current_objects - previous_objects
    previous_objects = current_objects

    if not new_objects:
        return
    
    for obj in new_objects:
        print("New object added: ", obj.name, type(obj))
        add_triangulate_modifier(obj)

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(new_object_added)
```

Comment: This script is working on it's own, however in an addon I am not able to get it to work. I am recieving the error "'AttributeError: '_RestrictData' object has no attribute 'objects'"

I've tried moving all the code in the __init__ file and putting this in the register function:
"bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(new_object_added)"

Comment: @ZakNelson because you are trying to access `bpy.data.objects` before the registration has completed where `bpy_data` still is in the state `<class 'bpy_restrict_state._RestrictData'>`. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8732/142292